# about problem with data size returned by dubbo generalization call

Tags: rpc, apache-dubbo

The size of the data returned by the return call affects whether it can be called normally;

problem with data size returned by dubbo generalization call;

A service is called remotely, and the amount of data returned by the interface is too large, causing the remote service call to fail.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. I think you will enjoy read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.